# How to pass a list as an environment variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I use a list as part of a Python program, and wanted to convert that to an environment variable.

So, it's like this:

```
list1 = ['a.1','b.2','c.3']
for items in list1:
    alpha,number = items.split('.')
    print(alpha,number)
```

which gives me, as expected:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

But when I try to set it as an environment variable, as:

```
export LIST_ITEMS = 'a.1', 'b.2', 'c.3'
```

and do:

```
list1 = [os.environ.get("LIST_ITEMS")]
for items in list1:
    alpha,number = items.split('.')
    print(alpha,number)
```

I get an error: `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

How do I modify the way I pass the list, or get it so that I have the same output as without using env variables?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd do it through the environment variables, but you can do this:

```
export LIST_ITEMS ="a.1 b.2 c.3"
```

And in Python:

```
list1 = [i.split(".") for i in os.environ.get("LIST_ITEMS").split(" ")] 

for k, v in list1:
    print(k, v)
```

Comment: The reason why I'd like to use env variables is because I can make a config file with stuff I'd use in the code, `source` it and if I need to make changes, just change the config file, rather than touch the code. I'll try yours and @martineau's answers and mark one of them as the answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: Why not put it in some storage (like a file) and refer to that storage?

Comment: I am getting this error when I export LIST_ITEMS: export: `=a.1 b.2 c.3': not a valid identifier

Comment: This is actually helpful in my case as I am storing my Env Vars in a JSON to pass them to SAM local invoke command.

Answer (score 147):

### The rationale

I recommend using JSON if you want to have data structured in an environment variable. JSON is simple to write / read, can be written in a single line, parsers exist, developers know it.

### The solution

To test, execute this in your shell:

```
$ export ENV_LIST_EXAMPLE='["Foo", "bar"]'
```

Python code to execute in the same shell:

```
import os
import json

env_list = json.loads(os.environ['ENV_LIST_EXAMPLE'])
print(env_list)
print(type(env_list))
```

gives

```
['Foo', 'bar']
<class 'list'>
```

### Package

Chances are high that you are interested in [`cfg_load`](https://github.com/MartinThoma/cfg_load)

### Debugging

If you see

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

You might have used single-quotes instead of double-quotes. While some JSON libraries accept that, [the JSON standard](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) clearly states that you need to use double-quotes:

```
Wrong: "['foo', 'bar']"
Right: '["foo", "bar"]'
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer to me.

Comment: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

Comment: @GonzaloGarcia I have no clue what you want to tell me. You might be interested in [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MartinThoma wouldn't `"['FOO', 'bar']"` be a more appropriate solution in general since then you could even use something like `"['FOO', $FOO]"` whereas encapsulating it in single quotes would prevent expansion of variables from terminal-side and seems counter-intuitive to me here or is there a specific reason to use single quotes?

Comment: @daniel451 Double quotes are correct JSON, single quotes are not. Depending on the JSON libary it might still work, but that's a decision to ignore this part of the standard: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: @MartinThoma sure, good catch, thanks!

Comment: @GonzaloGarcia I got the same error when I used double quotes on the outside and single inside. It appears to only work with `'["foo", "bar"]'`

Comment: @daniel451 For various reasons, generating JSON using shell string interpolation is a bad idea. If you need to generate JSON dynamically, use a tool like `jq` to do it for you.

Answer (score 31):

The [environs](https://pypi.org/project/environs/) PyPI package handles this use case well.

Make sure your env var is in csv format:

```
export GITHUB_REPO_PRIORITY="webargs,konch,ped"
```

Load a single setting from env var and coerce it to a list, int, etc:

```
from environs import Env

env = Env()
env.read_env()  # read .env file, if it exists

# parsing lists
#  env: GITHUB_REPOS=webargs,konch,ped
gh_repos = env.list("GITHUB_REPOS")  # => ['webargs', 'konch', 'ped']
#  env: COORDINATES=23.3,50.0
coords = env.list("COORDINATES", subcast=float)  # => [23.3, 50.0]
# provide default value if env not set
gh_repos = env.list("GITHUB_REPOS", []) # => []
```

Comment: Good answer but a bit frustrating because there is not example of how I should set it in the actual env. 

Solution is to set the env in csv format: eg.  `GITHUB_REPOS="webargs,konch,ped"`

Comment: Mmm, that's a very good point. I've edited the answer to include the env var values for each example

Answer (score 6):

If you want to set the environment variable using that format — `['a.1','b.2','c.3']` — this would work:

```
from ast import literal_eval

list1 = [literal_eval(e.strip()) for e in os.environ["LIST_ITEMS"].split(',')]
for item in list1:
    alpha,number = item.split('.')
    print alpha, number
```

Output:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
YOUR_VARIABLE="val1, val2"
```

In your Python code, Just split them as a list

```
import os
os.environ.get('YOUR_VARIABLE').split(', ')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export FILES="test1.txt,test2.txt"
```

In python script

```
import os
FILES = os.getenv("FILES").split(",")

print(FILES)
print(type(FILES))
```

Output:

```
['test1.txt', 'test2.txt']
<class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

In .env:

```
    VAR="val1,val2..."
```

In python code:

```py
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    load_dotenv('/path/to/your/file.env')
    value = os.getenv('VAR').split(',')
```

It's work for send for email's list

Answer (score 0):

We can also use **eval** function to transform a string to a list

Setup env vars:

```
export ENV_LIST_1='["Foo", "bar"]'
export ENV_LIST_2="['Foo', 'bar']"
```

Python code to execute in the same shell:

```
import os

env_list1 = eval(os.environ['ENV_LIST_1'])
env_list2 = eval(os.environ['ENV_LIST_2'])

print(env_list1, type(env_list1))
print(env_list2, type(env_list2))
```

Result:

```
['Foo', 'bar'], list
['Foo', 'bar'], list
```

Answer (score -2):

So no matter what I tried, i could not send emails to multiple recipients with **smtplib**. The only solution that worked out for me is to for loop the recipients

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.freesmtpservers.com')
# s.set_debuglevel(1)
recipients = ['01@ee.com','02@ee.com','03@ee.com','04@ee.com']

for x in recipients:
    msg = MIMEText("""body""")
    sender = 'me@example.com'
    msg['Subject'] = "subject line"
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = str(x)
    s.sendmail(sender, str(x), msg.as_string())
```

Comment: irrelevant to this question