# GCP gcloud deploy - escaping environmental variables

Tags: google-cloud-platform, syntax, environment-variables, gcloud

We have a working gcloud deploy command that we are trying add a new environmental variable to. Currently the working example looks like this:

```
gcloud functions deploy ftn_handler --set-env-vars APP_PROJECT_ID=my-project-id,CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET=my_bucket_name,ENVIRONMENT=development --runtime python37 --memory=1024MB  --trigger-resource my_project.appspot.com --trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize
```

Now, the env variable we want to add is a simple list, ex: MY_LIST=['val1', 'val2'], so at first we tried the obvious:

```
gcloud functions deploy ftn_handler --set-env-vars APP_PROJECT_ID=my-project-id,CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET=my_bucket_name,ENVIRONMENT=development,MY_LIST=['val1', 'val2'] --runtime python37 --memory=1024MB  --trigger-resource my_project.appspot.com --trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize
```

but immedaitely got back the error:

> (gcloud.functions.deploy) unrecognized arguments: val2]

So we started looking at escaping the values as indicated in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/escaping)

Based on the article we thought the following might work

```
gcloud functions deploy ftn_handler --set-env-vars APP_PROJECT_ID=my-project-id,CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET=my_bucket_name,ENVIRONMENT=development,MY_LIST=^,^val1,val2 --runtime python37 --memory=1024MB  --trigger-resource my_project.appspot.com --trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize
```

but we are still getting an error:

> (gcloud.functions.deploy) argument --set-env-vars: Bad syntax for dict arg: [^val1]

We've tried a number of variations using the escaping syntac but all have ended with an error of some sort. Any ideas on the proper syntax or if such a thing is even possible with --set-env-vars ?

Comment: I would use `--env-vars-file` so that command line escaping is not required.  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var

Comment: If you need an answer to escaping, you need to specify the OS that you are running the CLI on. Escaping is different for Linux and Windows.

Comment: Please add the answer here if you found the answer

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using python, and you would like to have listed values as an environment variable, I have found a useful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31352317/how-to-pass-a-list-as-an-environment-variable?answertab=active#tab-top) where  a LIST_ITEMS variable is created and then splitted by python code.

I have replicated this and can confirm that you can add the variable using the gcloud command:

```
gcloud functions deploy Your_Function --runtime python37 --set-env-vars LIST="a.1 b.2 c.3" --trigger-http
```